# kivy scrollview gets stuck

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a scrollview object in my Kivy app. The scrollview contains a boxlayout, which holds a certain amount of images. In runtime, the more images are added to this boxlayout. At the moment I try to adjust the scrollview to the changes by changing the scroll_y property and it works fine-ish. At some point it gets stuck (on around the 225th image) and i can't figure out how to solve this. Does Kivy have a way to automatically readjust the scrollview if changed? or is there a better way to solve this than what I did?

That's what I've been doing so far in python (inside the scrollview class):

```
   def on_scroll_y(self, instance, scroll_val):
        global main_screen, generate_id
        if scroll_val < get_scroll_distance() * scrolls_to_another_page:
            box = main_screen.ids.notebook_image # this is the boxlayout that holds the images
            new_image = MyImage() # just an image class
            new_image.id = next(generate_id)
            box.add_widget(new_image)
            self.scroll_y = new_image.height / box.height # this is my try to adjust the scroll value
```

That's how it's defined in the kv file:

```
           MyScrollView:
                bar_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
                id: notebook_scroll
                padding: 0
                spacing: 0
                do_scroll: (False, True)  # up and down
                BoxLayout:
                    padding: 0
                    spacing: 0
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    id: notebook_image
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    MyImage:

<MyImage>:
    source: 'images/notebook2.png'
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: False
    size: root.get_size_for_notebook() #not important for this case, just screen size manipulation
    size_hint: None, None
```

Answer (score 0):

When I answered your original question on this topic, I used the test:

```
 if scroll_val < 0.05:
```

But, I think that was a poor choice. The problem with my test (and with yours) is that as the `box.height` gets bigger (with added `Images`), the calculated new `scroll_y` gets smaller and smaller. Once the new `scroll_y` gets smaller than the test value (`0.05` in my case or `get_scroll_distance() * scrolls_to_another_page` in yours), then setting the new `scroll_y` value triggers the `on_scroll_y()` method again. That can result in an infinite loop. I think the best choice is to actually test for equality to `0.0`. In all my years of computer science, I have always avoided testing for equality of float values, but I believe this is an exception. So, I suggest changing your test to simply:

```
 if scroll_val == 0.0:
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just gets it stuck haha. However, i think i know what can solve this. Whenever i add another image to the boxlayout, it "glitches" or "bounces off", because the scroll_y value isn't set properly. I tried doing it this way:
self.scroll_y = self.scroll_y * box.height / old_height
 (i was trying to get it to be in the same position so nothing moves, as the height changes). Unfortunatly this formula didn't really work. If you have any idea of a better formula, i think I'll be able to take it from there :)

Comment: Try `self.scroll_y = new_image.height / (box.height + new_image.height)`